# Glowing/Flashing Effect on SVG D3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas, svg

May I know is it possible to apply a glowing/flashing effect to a SVG of D3js. I wish to do something similar as shown below.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.button {
  background-color: #004A7F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@-moz-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@-o-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

.button {
  -webkit-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
  -o-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
  animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
<button type="submit" class="button">Click me!</button>
```

And this flashing effect will be applied to the petal of the doughnut chart. Below is my source. I have tried to use the same logic in my code, however the effect doesn't shown as what is being expected. Notice that the effect does shown if I apply to the header tag. Any help is highly appreciate. Thanks.

```js
var dataset = [
    { name: 'Smooth', percent: 30.00 },
    { name: 'Moderation', percent: 30.00 },
    { name: 'Congestion', percent: 40.00 }
];

var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.percent })
    .sort(null)
    .padAngle(.03); //padding width (gap between 2 petal)

var w = 300,//width of graphics
    h = 300;//height of graphics

var outerRadius = w/2;
var innerRadius = 100;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#605A4C", "#787341" , "#784D41"]);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .innerRadius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attrs({
        width: w,
        height: h,
        class: 'shadow glowing'/*for multiple classes can be done it like this*/
    }).append('g')
    .attrs({
        transform: 'translate(' + w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ')'
    });
var path = svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attrs({
        d: arc,
        class: 'custom-header',/*adding a class*/
        fill: function(d, i) {
            console.log("top i" +i);
            return color(d.data.name);
        }
    });

path.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween('d', function(d) {
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate({ startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0 }, d);
        return function(t) {
            return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
    });


var restOfTheData = function() {
    var text = svg.selectAll('text')
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("dy", ".4em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.percent + "%";
        })
        .styles({
            fill: '#fff',
            'font-size': '10px'
        });

    var legendRectSize = 20;
    var legendSpacing = 7;
    var legendHeight = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;


    var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attrs({
            class: 'legend',
            transform: function(d, i) {
                console.log(i);
                console.log(d);
                //Just a calculation for x & y position
                return 'translate(-45,' + ((i * legendHeight) - 40) + ')';

            }
        });
    legend.append('rect')
        .attrs({
            width: legendRectSize,
            height: legendRectSize,
            rx: 20,
            ry: 40
        })
        .styles({
            fill: color,
            stroke: color
        });

    legend.append('text')
        .attrs({
            x: 30,
            y: 15
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        }).styles({
            fill: ' #C0C0C0',
            'font-size': '16px'
        });
};

setTimeout(restOfTheData, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #A09383;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

.widget {
    position: absolute;
    /*margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #A09383;
    border-radius: 5px;*/

}

.header {
    background-color: #29384D;
    height: 40px;
    color: #929DAF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #06060d;
    z-index:10;
    cursor: move;
}

.chart-container {
    padding: 25px;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
    filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
}
@-webkit-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

@-moz-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

@-o-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

.custom-header {
  -webkit-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite !important;
  -moz-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite  !important;
  -o-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite  !important;
  animation: glowing 1500ms infinite  !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" class="widget">
    <div id="mydivheader" class="header custom-header">Indicator</div>
    <div id="chart" class="Chart chart-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your style won't work for an svg path without modification. `background-color` doesn't set a background color for an svg path, `fill` does. You can add it to each rule where you reference background color:

```
@-webkit-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }

  0% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { fill: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}
```

```js
var dataset = [
    { name: 'Smooth', percent: 30.00 },
    { name: 'Moderation', percent: 30.00 },
    { name: 'Congestion', percent: 40.00 }
];

var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.percent })
    .sort(null)
    .padAngle(.03); //padding width (gap between 2 petal)

var w = 300,//width of graphics
    h = 300;//height of graphics

var outerRadius = w/2;
var innerRadius = 100;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#605A4C", "#787341" , "#784D41"]);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .innerRadius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attrs({
        width: w,
        height: h,
        class: 'shadow glowing'/*for multiple classes can be done it like this*/
    }).append('g')
    .attrs({
        transform: 'translate(' + w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ')'
    });
var path = svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attrs({
        d: arc,
        class: 'custom-header',/*adding a class*/
        fill: function(d, i) {
            console.log("top i" +i);
            return color(d.data.name);
        }
    });

path.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween('d', function(d) {
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate({ startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0 }, d);
        return function(t) {
            return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
    });


var restOfTheData = function() {
    var text = svg.selectAll('text')
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("dy", ".4em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.percent + "%";
        })
        .styles({
            fill: '#fff',
            'font-size': '10px'
        });

    var legendRectSize = 20;
    var legendSpacing = 7;
    var legendHeight = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;


    var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attrs({
            class: 'legend',
            transform: function(d, i) {
                console.log(i);
                console.log(d);
                //Just a calculation for x & y position
                return 'translate(-45,' + ((i * legendHeight) - 40) + ')';

            }
        });
    legend.append('rect')
        .attrs({
            width: legendRectSize,
            height: legendRectSize,
            rx: 20,
            ry: 40
        })
        .styles({
            fill: color,
            stroke: color
        });

    legend.append('text')
        .attrs({
            x: 30,
            y: 15
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        }).styles({
            fill: ' #C0C0C0',
            'font-size': '16px'
        });
};

setTimeout(restOfTheData, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #A09383;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

.widget {
    position: absolute;
    /*margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #A09383;
    border-radius: 5px;*/

}

.header {
    background-color: #29384D;
    height: 40px;
    color: #929DAF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #06060d;
    z-index:10;
    cursor: move;
}

.chart-container {
    padding: 25px;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
    filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
}
@-webkit-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  
  0% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { fill: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

@-moz-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  
  0% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { fill: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

@-o-keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  
  0% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { fill: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  
  0% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
  50% { fill: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000  !important; }
  100% { fill: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000  !important; }
}

.custom-header {
  -webkit-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite !important;
  -moz-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite  !important;
  -o-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite  !important;
  animation: glowing 1500ms infinite  !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" class="widget">
    <div id="mydivheader" class="header custom-header">Indicator</div>
    <div id="chart" class="Chart chart-container"></div>
</div>
```

Though d3 transitions are pretty capable of this sort of effect too...

Comment: Thank you so so much. Andrew. That's a new info for me. :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help

Comment: In fact, I am just started with d3js actually. Will get to know it deeper. Meanwhile, do you have any good source for me to refer? :)

Comment: Not off the top of my head, I'll see if can think of any. Just make sure to note what version of d3 your are looking at when looking at examples - d3v3 and d3v4 have a number of differences that can break code and change approaches.

Comment: I am using d3 version 4. You are definitely a helpful man. May luck with you always. :)

Comment: @cypatrick IMO, Scott Murray's book is by far the best one for beginners. It's online and free. http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345